# Javascript function not working when called in a form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML

```
<form> 
    <p>
        Enter the total stock value: <input id="total" type="number"onkeyup="calculate()">
    </p>
    <p>
        Enter the agreed commision rate:<input id="commision" type="number"> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="calculate" type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Result">
    </p> 
</form>
```

and this is my Javascript

```
calculate = function() {
    var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
    var commision = document.getElementById('commision').value; 
    document.getElementById('calculate').value = parseFloat(total) / 100 * parseFloat(commision);
}

$(document).keyup(function(e) {     
    if(e.keyCode== 27) {
        $("form")[0].reset();
    }
});
```

Now, if my form is not wrapped in a form tag my Calculate function works perfectly, but when it's in a form tag I'll get an error in the console saying "Uncaught TypeError: calculate is not a function".
I tried without the form tag, but then the reset() function is not working..

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you have a element with id calculate, element's ids are copied as properties of the form object(also to window properties) so in your case `calculate` is referring to the dom element when used within the scope of the form which have overridden the function

```
<input id="txtcalculate" type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Result">
```